# Android - Getting battery level null when first time ask

Tags: java, android, intentfilter, batterylevel, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to get battery level from a service. I am getting level successfully. But I have one problem. And that is **when I try to get battery level for the first time then I get** ***null***. **But when I ask after some seconds later, then I get exact level.** I am not understanding why this is happening.

Here is my code to get battery level:-

```
String bLevel;
private String getBatteryLevel(){
        BroadcastReceiver cBReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                context.unregisterReceiver(this);
                int currentLevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
                int currentScale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
                int batteryLevel;
                if (currentLevel >= 0 && currentScale > 0) {
                    batteryLevel = (currentLevel * 100) / currentScale;
                    bLevel = Integer.toString(batteryLevel) + " percent";
                }
            }
        };
        IntentFilter cIFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(cBReceiver, cIFilter);
        return bLevel;
    }
```

Please see the code. I don't know why I get ***null*** as my battery level when I ask for the first time. Please help

Comment: I would recommend not to pack a BroadcastReceiver into a method.

Comment: Or AT LEAST unregister...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can read. You are running your code linearly, and returning a non-initialized value

```
String bLevel;
// stuffs ... stuffs ... stuffs...
return bLevel;
```

This String is null, then, you are registering the receiver. Once that event is broadcasted, then you change your variable, and it has the correct information.

This breaks OO paradigm.

Comment: Sorry, I am not understanding what are you trying to say. Here, **bLevel** is a global variable and now should I make it inner variable?

Comment: No. You are making a program that is "procedural", in an Object Oriented system. You are breaking the paradigm..... Think of it like this, you have 1 `Pointer` to code execution. it runs its entire code list, performing 1 by 1... and you register your broadcast to receive the NEXT event related to battery level.... lets say it will happen in 10 seconds.... what do you have in that variable until those seconds pass? `null`.

Comment: What should I do now?

Comment: @MuhammadJobayer the method has to wait for the BroadcastReceiver

Comment: @MuhammadJobayer You should understand `Thread`s as a first step, then make a small `if(bLevel!=null){return bLevel;} else {return "Gathering data";}`